# Why we use ObjectId(id) in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

What is the purpose of using Object Id here?

```
app.get('/product/:id', async(req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
  const product = await productCollection.findOne(query);
  res.send(product);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array as default mongo use it as ObjectId.

So the purpose you parse the `id` it because `id` its a String and in you database `_id` it not a string it an `ObjectId`.

**Note:** if you are using mongoose you don't need to parse the id to ObjectId cause mongoose auto cast that field to `ObjectId`